# Gmail History list is not giving complete data

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to get history from historyId which gmail api watch() gives

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list

I am getting `historyId` in the response like below

```
{
    historyId: 12345
}
```

I tried adding `fields` argument with no luck.

request to https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/history?startHistoryId=12345&fields=historyId,history(id%2Cmessages) is also failing

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The response tells you that nothing has happened since the time your `startHistoryId` represents. If you send yourself a mail and try again with the same `startHistoryId`, you will get a new message as result.

If you are getting the historyId from `watch()`, it is another issue. The `historyId` you get in the push notification simply states the current `historyId` of the label you are watching. Think about it. How should Google know when you last synced? When you get a push notification, you need to use the `historyId` you stored since last time in your request.