# When is new Gmail API History ID generated

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to design an algorithm to maintain a list of new INBOX messages using a combination the watch()/push notification, with the user.history and user.messages gmail apis. HistoryID documentation is unclear.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync#partial
indicates

**"You can also use push notifications to trigger partial synchronization in real-time and only when necessary, thereby avoiding needless polling."** -- My question is **HOW?**

Which event on the email account triggers an incremented HistoryID?

If I guess HistoryID I get in the push notification the **latest** historyId of the label specified, then I should be able to use that HistoryID as the starting HistoryId in the User.History.List call, but when I do I just get an json response which is another higher HistoryID.  So, if I'm specifying messagesadded and watching INBOX, why is the call to History API with the most current HistoryID returning no HistoryList objects?

I have read [Gmail API users.watch - no details for historyId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797416/gmail-api-users-watch-no-details-for-historyid) and [Gmail History list is not giving complete data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248048/gmail-history-list-is-not-giving-complete-data)

and I'm unclear as to how to design the algorithm to use push notifications in conjunction with the other apis to do a partial sync to maintain a running inventory on new INBOX messages, as per the documentation.

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I have no code that incorporates the HistoryID I receive from the push notifications, because I don't know what it is used for. I just notificed when i took the historyid I got from my push notification and plugged it in here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list, I am getting a 200 Response, with only the following json object { historyId: [historyidvalue]} -- no other data

Comment: @arod I'm also gettting that, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Exacly the same issue here!
It looks like it's a matter of delay.
If you wait for some time before request the `list`, you eventually get the "history" array of messages.
Unfortunately, the time you have to wait vary very largely from a couple of seconds to several minutes.
Not a very reliable API....

Answer (score 0):

this issue really sad, google just send historyId with empty history list. But why cant add emailId or property that this history binds with new message arrived?
To solve this problem u need remember time when u last time fetch email messages with total counter messages in Inbox, next, when u get google pub/sub message and it has empty history object - u need get new total counter of messages in Inbox label - if there is differences - next what u need is fetch email messages using:
or

1. max count value = differences between  of total counter messages,
   means add query to get messages by max result
   or
2. using date time from your last update - means add query to get messages by date time.
   Really bad that google make such bad implementation for pub sub for new messages.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).